# Allow embedded videos in website while keeping youtube blocked in network

Tags: iframe, proxy, youtube, vpn, blocked

I am working on a client project that has embedded youtube videos in it. This website is for the learning purpose of their employees. They have blocked youtube in their company. I need to play those embedded videos and they won't unblock youtube. Also, embedded videos are more than 1000. Please suggest some method/code. Website is in PHP and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

embedded youtube videos means, you just fetch the youtube data from there website. If some is blocked the URL then it is not possible to access the youtube videos.
On think you can do, You have to download the all videos and upload on your own website. 
I know its to hard to do that.